# Create a generic method to combine multiple .close() connection methods

Tags: java, generics

I have these 4 methods which each close a different connection type, meaning each of those has a different input object. Each method calls the close() method on the provided input object. Is there a way to combine those methods into one, taking in a generic object? I have no way to implement an interface on the provided objects or extend them.

```
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.mail.Transport;

private void close(Statement stm) {
    if(stm == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        stm.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.error("Error while closing statement", ex);
    }
}

private void close(java.sql.Connection con) {
    if(con == null) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.error("Error while closing connection", ex);
    }
}
private void close(javax.jms.Connection con) {
        if(con == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            con.close();
        } catch(JMSException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while closing JMS connection", ex);
        }
    }

private void close(Transport transport) {
        if(transport == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            logger.error("Error while closing mail transport", ex);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you for your answers regarding Java 1.7. Unfortunately our servers are running Java 1.6, so is there any solution for that?

Comment: Are they all type of SQL connection?

Comment: You don't actually need this at all. First, you can avoid the whole problem via try-with-resources. Second, closing a Statement closes any ResultSets associated with it, and closing a java.sql.Connection closes any Statements.

Comment: @EJP Your answer seems ok, but we have to take into account also the java version. If he uses Java7+ then your solution seems a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection. 
First sample give you support for try() with resources:

```
@Test
public void testRes() throws Exception {
    try(ClosableWrapper<StringWriter> rs = new ClosableWrapper<>(new StringWriter())){
        Writer wr = rs.getResource();
    }
}
static class ClosableWrapper<T> implements AutoCloseable{
    private T resource;
    private String closeMethod = "close";

    public ClosableWrapper(T resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public ClosableWrapper(T resource, String closeMethod) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.closeMethod = closeMethod;
    }

    public T getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        if(resource!=null){
            Method m = resource.getClass().getMethod(closeMethod);
            m.invoke(resource);
        }
    }
}
```

or just one method:

```
public void close(Object resource) throws Exception {
    if(resource!=null){
        Method m = resource.getClass().getMethod("close");
        m.invoke(resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are your classes, use the [`AutoCloseable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface and put them in a try-with-resource.

Comment: @EM-Creations Yes it does. You missed the second sentence.